# Why can’t Iron Man’s repulsors be Arc reactors?

Tags: iron-man, marvel

Iron Man's Arc reactor powers his suit, but also fires beams of energy.

So why can't the repulsors on the gauntlets be Arc reactors, too?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear and I am not certain what you were asking. Please try and clarify your question. I have left a simple response below hoping to clarify any confusion between the three technologies: arc reactor, repulsor and unibeam.

Answer (score 7):

#### The [Arc Reactor](http://marvel.wikia.com/Arc_Reactor) and the [Repulsor](http://marvel.wikia.com/Repulsor) gauntlet are two entirely different technologies. One generates power for the other. The arc reactor is likely the most efficient energy producing technology on the Marvel Cinematic Universe's Earth.

[image]

- As you can see from this early prototype, the arc reactor on Stark's chest is providing power for the repulsor in his hand. The arc reactor provides power for all of the energy using systems on the Iron Man armor.
- The repulsor on the Cinematic Iron Man armor, is part short-range weapon system and part navigational/directional flight aid. It is more important as a flight stabilizer than providing additional power to the suit.
- The arc reactor does not fire beams of energy. Whenever you see Stark using his chest plate to fire a beam of energy, it is a system overlay in the armor for a repulsor technology he has dubbed the **[Unibeam](http://ironman.wikia.com/wiki/Unibeam_%28film%29)**. It is a larger, stronger repulsor weapon.

> - The Unibeam is a secondary repulsion blast that comes out of Iron Man's RT. It has to be used wisely, as if it is used too much, it can rapidly drain the suit's power. It has also been shown that it can be used as a search light. First used by the Mark II armor, the Unibeam has to be charged, therefore it has been used rarely.

[image]